# C# - No overload for method "getal" takes 1 argument

Tags: c#

I'm new to classes and I have this task to show the written number on a MessageBox but I get an error and I don't know how to fix it.
Help will be appreciated :)

```
 private void buttonmet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            teller.getal(txtNummer.Text);

        }
```

Here's my method

```
 public int getal()
        {
            _a += _a;
            return _a;
        }
```

Comment: Your method doesn't expect an argument but you are passing it one.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass txtNummer.Text to getal it doesn't use the value.

Comment: No offence, but this is very basic C#, in fact, it's fundamental procedural programming. Perhaps you would be better off running through some simple programming tutorials rather than asking questions here?

Comment: Could you explain what you want `getal` to do?

Comment: Like there is a textbox , if I put 50 on that textbox then click on the button, I want the number 50 come on a MessageBox and I have to use getal as the method

Comment: Ugh, Dutch code. Take it from someone who cringes every time he looks back at his old school code, kid... write your methods and variables in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying there's not method getal that has a string parameter.

You're invoking getal with txtNumber.text (string) as argument and the compiler is looking for a getal method with a string parameter and can't find it. The existing getal method doesn't take any parameters.

```
public int getal(string x)
        {
            _a += _a;
            return _a;
        }
```

Of course you still need to define what you are going to do with the string parameter "x" defined in getal but now it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing a string argument to `getal()`? You can see from the definition of this method that it does not accept any arguments.

And that's exactly what the error message is telling you: Of all the overloads for this method (there appears to be only one of them in this case), none of them take 1 argument.

The fix? Don't pass any arguments to methods that do not accept any arguments.